# Python if then else multiple ordered substring search

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write code to search a data frame field for a particular substring. If there is a match it gets tagged according to the substring search criteria.

For example I have a data frame with a field to hold the skill for each member of the team e.g.

```
Skill
=====
Junior AI, Google & MS Cloud Platform
Senior AI, Google & MS Cloud Platform
Project Management
Any Programme Management
Financial Management
Engineer
Full Stack Engineer
```

The logic is as follows:

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(SKILL) LIKE '%AI%CLOUD%' THEN 'Data Member'
CASE WHEN UPPER(SKILL) LIKE '%PRO%MANAGE%' THEN 'Project Manager'
CASE WHEN UPPER(SKILL) LIKE '%FINANC%' THEN 'Finance Member'
ELSE 'Other'
```

so far I have been able to to create a field as follows:

```
df["Skill Type"] = df.loc[df['Skill'].str.contains('AI.*Cloud', regex=True)]
df["Skill Type"] = df["Skill Type"].apply(lanbda x: 'Data Member' if not pd.isnull(x) else 'Other')
```

However this misses the UPPER check and also when I run this again for the Project or Finance members it completely overwrites the previous search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default "Other" value for the entire column. Then update values as needed using `loc`:

```
df["Skill Type"] = "Other"
df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('.*AI.*CLOUD', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Data Member"
df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('.*PRO.*MANAGE', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Project Manager"
df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('FINANC', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Finance Member"

>>> df
                                   Skill       Skill Type
0  Junior AI, Google & MS Cloud Platform      Data Member
1  Senior AI, Google & MS Cloud Platform      Data Member
2                     Project Management  Project Manager
3               Any Programme Management  Project Manager
4                   Financial Management   Finance Member
5                               Engineer            Other
6                    Full Stack Engineer            Other
```

Comment: Amazing, how do i default all others to 'Other'? - I've just tested the following: this works so for anyone else the way to extrapolate this out to the other searches is as follows: <br/> df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('AI.*CLOUD', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Data Member" <br/> df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('PRO.*MANAGE', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Project Manager" <br/> df.loc[df['Skill'].str.upper().str.contains('FINANC', regex=True),"Skill Type"] = "Finance Member"

Comment: The first line of the answer assigns the default.